# CMS for posting code snippets

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I'm looking to build a website for people to post code snippets. I work in an office where people are always writing quick scripts for computational biology, and we need a place for people to post their scripts for others to reference in the future. Is there a good CMS for this?

There are lots of sites like this out there - djangosnippets.org is a great model. I also really like Github Gists, but we'd prefer to have our own website, rather than everybody posting their own Gists.

As of now, my plan is to use drupal and define a "script" content type, with a little "Download" button. But this seems like a common enterprise problem - is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Snipt.net](http://snipt.net/) is [open source](https://github.com/lionburger/snipt) and quite slick.